# How to get set elements in the same sequence as in a Spring bean definition

Tags: spring, collections

I have a lot of bean definitions that look similar to this

```
        <bean id="TransformationMapOrganization " class="com.artifact_software.adt.plugin.transformation.RemoveColumnsTransformationImpl">
                <property name="pluginId" value="Remove Division, Department, and Cost Code" />
                <property name="dataStoreName" value="person_data"/>
                <property name="columnNames">
                    <set>
                        <value>Division</value>
                        <value>Dept Code</value>
                        <value>Cost Code</value>
                    </set>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

In the code, the columnNames are defined as:

```
protected List<String> columnNames;
```

It appears that erroneous duplicate values are ignored rather causing an error which is good. I hope that I can count on that since it does make life easier!

1. What set implementation will Spring use?
2. What is the correct way to iterate through columnNames to get the columnNames in the same sequence as they are specified in the bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set the implementation class via `<set set-class="com.my.SetImpl" />`, ([see current doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#xsd-schemas-util-set)). (`com.my.SetImpl` *must implement* `java.util.Set`)

   - alternatively: define `targetClass` on your `SetFactoryBean`...
   - If omit, [current spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/SetFactoryBean.java#L88), will use `java.util.LinkedHashSet`.
2. More correct, reliable & future-safe it would be to map `columnNames` as `java.util.Set` *not* as a `List` (+ to use `set-class`).

   > If no set-class attribute is supplied, *the container chooses* a Set implementation.

---

(in your case,) Obviously spring manages to convert from set to list "smoothly" ("by hand" it's also easy done thx to api design). Spring (seems to) also preserves you *distinct* entries, `LinkedHashSet` implementation additionally guarantees/should "preserve order"...

Comment: Thank you. I will fix the code to be a set. I am cleaning up a big project that has an inconsistent usage of Sets and Lists but works in spite of that. It has a plug-in architecture and the plug-ins use Lists and Sets according to the taste at the moment of the author. Going through all of them with a single purpose of fixing that issue.
I appreciate the time that you took to provide a complete answer with references that will help me answer any followup questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bean definition and field names are different. Change

```
<property name="ColumnNames">
```

to

```
<property name="columnNames">
```

Comment: Thanks. Does not answer the question but probably saved me from a lot of chasing my tail while testing!